# Subtitle does not show up in scrartcl document

Tags: titles, koma-script

I would like to add a subtitle to my article and have read that it is best to use the scrartcl class. However, the problem is not solved, the subtitle doesn't show up.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl} %bei Bedarf titlepage
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[autostyle=true, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}
\begin{document}
\title{Title that shows up}
\subtitle{Subtitle that should show up but does not}
\author{My name\thanks{My varsity which shows up in a footnote} which shows up}
\maketitle
Thanks for your help!  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove package `titling` to really use the KOMA-Script commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl} %bei Bedarf titlepage
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{a4wide}% <- geometry would be better to change the page layout
%\usepackage{titling}% <- remove this
\usepackage[autostyle=true, german=quotes]{csquotes}
%\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}% <- remove this
\begin{document}
\title{Title that shows up}
\subtitle{Subtitle that should show up but does not}
\author{My name\thanks{My varsity which shows up in a footnote} which shows up}
\maketitle
Thanks for your help!
\end{document}
```

[image]